# RVM: Unable to use shorthand expression after setting default

Tags: rvm

I've been using RVM for quite some time now and have been very happy with it. But just today when I tried to be a little adventurous and set a particular gemset of my default ruby as the default gemset, the shorthand way of switching gemsets has stopped working.

My default ruby is set to ruby-1.8.7-p330.

> rvm default gemset list

gives the following gemsets

> projA
>   projB
>   projC

I've bee  able to use shorthand formats

> rvm use default@projA
>   rvm use default@projB
>   rvm use default@projC

till now without issues. However, ever since I set one of the gemsets as default,

> rvm use default@projA --default

all of the above shorthands set the projA gemset.

Is there any way I can unset the default tag on a gemset?
Though I can still use other shorthands like

> rvm use @projB

I don't want to do that since a lot of other stuff depend on the way these shorthand expressions are used. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RVM the default gemset points to the global gemset of your RVM ruby version. When I set a particular gemset as the default using

```
rvm use default@projA --default
```

This set the projA gemset as the default gemset of my default ruby version.
Seems like the only way to undo this is to dig into .rvm in the home directory and remove the defaults line from the ruby's environment file.